# yarn uses wrong version on workspaces

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a huge project, which I was will simplify for the issue, with 2 workspaces.

The main packages looks like

```
  workspaces: [ 'workspace-A', 'workspace-B' ]
```

My `workspace-A` has a dependency to external package (here, `jest`), in a needed version

```
  name: "workspace-A",
  dependencies: {
    "jest": "<27.0.0"
  }
```

My `workspace-B` has a dependency to the same package, but doesn't care about its version.

```
  name: "workspace-B"
  dependencies: {
    "jest": "*"
  }
```

After a `yarn install` (with yarn v3), I was expecting yarn to automatically install `jest` with a `26.x.x` version in my main `node_modules`.
Instead, the node_modules of the main project contains jest `26.x.x`, and the node_modules of the `workspace-B` contains jest `27.x.x`. It's OK for my, even if I find this weird, but the thing is the `workspace-A` now uses jest `27.x.x`!
I succeeded make it work by adding a resolution field in the main package file, but it's not ideal, as this package doesn't need jest.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
  }
```

My 2 questions are

- Why is yarn installing 2 versions of jest, is there a way to prevent this?
- Is there a configuration somewhere I should put to specify to the workspace-A to not use something from workspace-B?

Thanks for reading